# Azure functions with service bus: Unable to "complete" and access properties of a brokered message

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

This is my working code in a console app:

**Writer (working code):**

```
static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting..");

        string connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");
        
        QueueClient Client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, "xxx");

        // Create message, passing a string message for the body.
        BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage("");

        // Set some addtional custom app-specific properties.
        message.Properties["UserCode"] = "HELLOOO22353";
        message.Properties["UserId"] = "4511";

        try
        {
            // Send message to the queue.
            Client.Send(message);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Complete..");
        //Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

**Reader: (working code)**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting");

        string connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");

        QueueClient Client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, "xxx");

        OnMessageOptions options = new OnMessageOptions();
        options.AutoComplete = false;
        options.AutoRenewTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

        Client.OnMessage((message) =>
        {
            try
            {
                string sMessage = " UserCode: " + message.Properties["UserCode"];

                Console.WriteLine("Found new User - " + sMessage);
                

                // Remove message from queue.
                message.Complete();

             
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                // Indicates a problem, unlock message in queue.
                message.Abandon();
            }
        }, options);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

**Now, this is the code I have in Azure functions which isn't working:**

```
public static void Run(BrokeredMessage myMessage, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myMessage}");

    log.Info("1111");
    log.Info(myMessage.MessageId);  // this works
    myMessage.Complete(); // fails: Microsoft.ServiceBus: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

    log.Info(myMessage.Properties["UserCode"].ToString());  // fails: myMessage.Properties is empty for some reason
   
}
```

What I'm failing to understand is why the Reader console app is able to read and complete message correctly but Azure function one (which is essentially based on the same idea) isn't. Both the codes are using the same version of Windows.ServiceBus package.

Comment: If you could add the full stacktrace of the exception that's being thrown that would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to complete the message yourself when using the ServiceBus trigger with Azure Functions. [The ServiceBus trigger automatically uses `PeekLock` mode and will handle automatically completing, abandoning and renewing the message lock for you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---peeklock-behavior). You can also [take control the finer details of this behavior via `host.json` settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---hostjson-properties) for your function.

Comment: The message remains in the "Active" queue if I don't complete it

Comment: Ok, so we probably need to sync up on terminology here a bit, but is "Active" queue the name of your actual queue in ServiceBus? 'Cause there's no such thing as an "Active" queue natively to SB. Essentially, the Azure Functions ServiceBus trigger is performing that very same message consumption loop you pasted as your "Reader". There should ultimately be no difference in what your function sees in the BrokeredMessage vs what your original Reader code saw in it.